# SQL command single column data to another table

Tags: sql, database, copy, duplicates

I have a question regarding a SQL query. I have 2 tables:

**STUDENT**

```
student_ID (int, NOT allowed nulls)
class_ID (int, NOT allowed nulls)
email (varchar(50), NOT allowed nulls)
```

**COMPLETED**

```
student_ID (int, NOT allowed nulls)
completed (bool, NOT allowed nulls)
random_code (allowed nulls)
```

`Student` is filled with student id's and I want each `student_ID` in the table `STUDENT` also in `student_ID` in the table `COMPLETED` and for default I want completed in `COMPLETED` to be false.

Now I have the following query that does not yet work as I want it to:

```
INSERT INTO COMPLETED (student_ID) 
   SELECT student_ID FROM STUDENT
```

This does not work yet because the `completed` column in `COMPLETED` is not assigned and therefore is `NULL` which is not allowed. How do I finish my query that it assigns the completed bool to `FALSE` and also copies the student id's from `STUDENT` into `COMPLETED`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS?? MySQL? SQL Server? Postgres? Oracle? IBM DB2???? Please update your tags!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this (if you're using **SQL Server** - you weren't clear on that in your question):

```
INSERT INTO COMPLETED (student_ID, completed) 
   SELECT student_ID, 0
   FROM STUDENT
```

If you want to provide a value, you have to add `completed` to the list of column of the `INSERT` statement, and since you want to set all those values to "false" (or `0` in SQL Server), you just provide that value in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @NiekJonkman you should consider accepting the answer if it help you.